# Speed up find_by search in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-server-2008

I've got a table called `Staging` into which I place all the data from an excel spreadsheet, get the ID number from it by looking up the existing model/table, and then compare it with the current database which is SQL Server 2008.

My code is as follows:

```
def compare 

require 'rubygems'
require 'spreadsheet'
require 'set'

Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
file_full_path = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../../SISlist.xls"))
book = Spreadsheet.open(file_full_path) #Select excel file
sheet = book.worksheet 0 #Select 1st worksheet
app,server,env = 0

for i in 1..500
  row = sheet.row(i)

    if row[0].to_s != "" # Makes sure no empty cells are saved
     row.each do |t|
     app = App.find_by_name(row[0].to_s)
     server = Server.find_by_name(row[2].to_s)
     env = Environment.find_by_code(row[3].to_s)
    end
Staging.create(:app => app.id, :server => server.id, :environment => env.id)
  end
 end
end
```

The problem I'm having now is that it takes extremely long to carry out this method (almost 20 seconds), when all my other methods of similar sort don't take that long.

Any way to speed up this process or maybe my flow of work is incorrect and hence the whole architecture is wrong?

Help needed

Comment: You might be able to use [batched find](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/23/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-batched-find)

Comment: @jaydel would that work with RoR 3? Because it says 2.3 so it may be depreciated?

Comment: Yeah, it appears so. sorry for the bad link. Here's a better one--a great [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: thanks @jaydel, will surely look at it

Comment: What are you doing this for? `row.each do |t|` ?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott in order to read the Excel file, using the gem `spreadsheet`. Otherwise I can't get the information off the spreadsheet

Comment: @jaydel how exactly would I implement the batch feature in my case? I'm having problems :S

Comment: Do you have indexes on your database for the fields you are searching by? That would help considerably in the look-up. Otherwise I suggest benchmarking the script to see what takes the most time.

Comment: @teenOmar -- Can you confirm that only 500 entries are being created in Staging for each time you run the method? I think many more might be created.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Actually less than 500 entries are being created, I just used 500 for future references if the Excel Spreadsheet has more fields. At the moment there are 224 fields, so not many more are created

Answer (score 1):

To speed up try

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  500.times do |i|
    row = sheet.row(i)
    if row[0].to_s != "" # Makes sure no empty cells are saved
      app = App.find_by_name(row[0].to_s)
      server = Server.find_by_name(row[2].to_s)
      env = Environment.find_by_code(row[3].to_s)
      Staging.create(:app => app.id, :server => server.id, :environment => env.id)
     end
  end
end
```

also are you aware that `app,server,env = 0` doesn't initialize all values with zero?

Comment: Oh? I thought it'd initialize them?  otherwise can I just state their existence without initializing them? Tried your code, but I get this error message `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id`. Any ideas why?

Comment: I managed to get it working, but the error that came up was due to the `500.times do |i|` loop, not sure why though. Using the `transaction` did not increase it in speed unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: I missed one end check https://gist.github.com/1261838 it should do the same thing. I'll be back in a few hours will try to speed up execution.

Comment: you're a genius, the problem was the `if` statement. Using the `unless row[0].blank?` sped it up by half at least. But if performance could be sped up even more it would be awesome. Also, the `500.times do` doesn't work, always creates an error, hence I used `for i in 1..500`

Comment: Note: this version doesn't do the row.each --- I really think that in for original version you were reading each column for each row.

Comment: I agree with Jesse and my apologizes for `500.times` n-1 bug, again :(

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a couple hundred rows then you could try doing it in three steps:

1. Spin through the spreadsheet to collect all the App, Server, and Environment names/codes.
2. Bulk load your App, Server, and Environment into hashes.
3. Spin through the spreadsheet again to do your `Staging.create` calls.

Something like this:

```
sets = {
    :apps         => Set.new,
    :servers      => Set.new,
    :environments => Set.new
}
(1 .. 500).select { |i| !sheet.row(i).to_s.empty? }.each do |i|
    sets[:apps].add(row[0].to_s)
    #...
end

# You could just pull in the ids and names here rather than whole objects too.
sets[:apps] = Set.where(:name => sets[:apps].to_a).each_with_object({ }) { |a,h| h[a.name] = a.id }
#...

(1 .. 500).select { |i| !sheet.row(i).to_s.empty? }.each do |i|
    Staging.create(
        :app => sets[:apps][row[0].to_s],
        #...
    )
end
```

Basically I'm guessing that your biggest hit is calling `find_by...` over and over again instead of just doing it once.